# unable to enable ssh1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

First, let me begin by saying that I am aware that SSH1 is totally inferior to SSH2. Now, having said that...

I am trying to enable SSH1 and am unable to do so. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` there's this line:

```
Protocol 2
```

I change it to this:

```
Protocol 2,1
```

I then do `sudo service ssh restart` and then do `telnet 127.0.0.1 22` and what I get back is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1`. If SSH1 were enabled what I should be getting back should be starting with `SSH-1.99` but it isn't.

Now let's say I change the `Protocol` line to this:

```
Protocol 1
```

I then do `sudo service ssh restart` and now I get this when I do `telnet 127.0.0.1 22`:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Maybe newer versions of OpenSSH disable SSH1 support all together? The version I was trying it on was 14.04. Other versions I tried it on:

- Ubuntu 12.04 / OpenSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
- Ubuntu 10.04 / OpenSSH-2.0-OpenSSH-5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7.1

Each of these behaved similarly.

Comment: have you tried loggin with `ssh -1 localhost`  ?

Comment: `ssh -1 localhost` is telling the OpenSSH client to connect using SSHv1. But that won't make a difference if the server is running v2.0 only. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-5.1 and http://www.snailbook.com/docs/protocol-1.5.txt

Comment: I mean, after setting `Protocol 1`in `sshd_config`

Comment: `telnet 127.0.0.1 22` is a sufficient test. If that returned `SSH-2.0` and `ssh -1 localhost` succeeded the most likely explanation would be that the `-1` was being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate `rsa1` host keys if you want to run server with SSH1:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa1 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
```

and specify the keys in the `sshd_config`:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
```

Later on you need to specify some authentication method that is supported by this ancient protocol, otherwise you will end up like this:

```
$ ssh -1 localhost
Permission denied.
```

But it still (unfortunately) somehow works on Ubuntu (tested on 15.10).

**But this is not advisable, since the protocol is old and broken. Do not use it for any production stuff!**

Comment: Good catch! I'll try to verify when I get home but I'm pretty sure that that's the issue. Thanks!